# Airflow custom jinja2 filters

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

I am trying to add custom filters for my airflow jinja2 templates.

Since my folders in S3 are like

> /year/month/day/

, my purpose is to use yesterday_ds in the Variables screen like this:

> s3://logs.web.com/AWSLogs/{{ yesterday_ds | get_year }}/{{ yesterday_ds | get_month }}/{{ yesterday_ds | get_day }}/

I have seen in a PR (which I think is already merged..) that you can do this with the parameter 'user_defined_filters' in the dag_args parameter in the dag object creation [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2258/files)

The problem is that even when doing it, it says 'no filter named get_year', for example.

This is my code:

dag.py

```
   dag = DAG(
        dag_id='dag-name',
        default_args=utils.get_dag_args(user_defined_filters=utils.get_date_filters()),
        template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
        schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
        max_active_runs=1,
        )
```

utils.py

```
def get_dag_args(**kwargs):
return {
    'owner'               : kwargs.get('owner', 'owner_name'),
    'depends_on_past'     : kwargs.get('depends_on_past', False),
    'start_date'          : kwargs.get('start_date', datetime.now() - timedelta(1)),
    'email'               : kwargs.get('email', ['blabla@blabla.com']),
    'retries'             : kwargs.get('retries', 5),
    'provide_context'     : kwargs.get('provide_context', True),
    'retry_delay'         : kwargs.get('retry_delay', timedelta(minutes=5)),
    'user_defined_filters': get_date_filters()
    }


def get_date_filters():
    return dict(
        get_year=lambda date_string: date_string.strftime('%Y'),
        get_month=lambda date_string: date_string.strftime('%m'),
        get_day=lambda date_string: date_string.strftime('%d'),
        )
```

Does anybody see where I am mistaken? Thank you!

*EDIT*

Printing this after the dag definition, shows no custom filters, unfortunately :(.

```
jinja_env = dag.get_template_env()
print(jinja_env.filters)
```

Also, if I try to add it directly as a DAG object parameter, as it shows in the tests @ tests/models.py:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/dag.py] __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_defined_filters'
```

*EDIT 2*

Ok what I see is that I have the version 1.8.0 and this one does not have the filters. Anybody knows how to download the 1.8.2rc one via pip? Or we cant?

Comment: Thank you for following up on this, and yes your usage looks correct. I suggest the question title be changed to include `airflow v1.8.0` since the question and answer here seems to be limited to that scope.

Answer (score 4):

Airflow has support for custom filters and macros now

Working code example:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def first_day_of_month(any_day):
    return any_day.replace(day=1)


def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=4)  # this will never fail
    return next_month - timedelta(days=next_month.day)


def isoformat_month(any_date):
    return any_date.strftime("%Y-%m")


with DAG(
        dag_id='generate_raw_logs',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=120),
        catchup=False,
        user_defined_macros={
            'first_day_of_month': first_day_of_month,
            'last_day_of_month': last_day_of_month,
        },
        user_defined_filters={
            'isoformat_month': isoformat_month
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Airflow packaging name has been changed on pip. 1.8.2rc1 can be downloaded using pip install apache-airflow instead.

Also, note that according to the mailling list, they are currently working on releasing 1.8.2rc4 as 1.8.2.

Comment: It's described in the Resources & links chapter of the documentation (https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/project.html)